# Rails 4 devise choose facebook application before request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I'm using devise for authenticate to facebook application and have following config

```
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['APP_ID'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['SECRET_KEY'],
              {:scope => FACEBOOK_CONFIG['AUTH_FB_SCOPE']}
```

Thats fine until I have only one Facebook application. But what can I do when I have e.g. 2 and want do decide to which of them authenticate before request?

Comment: Do you mean two environments e.g. production, development? :)

Comment: i guess you are looking for something like this http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/how-to-create-multiple-facebook-omniauth-strategies-for-the-same-application/

Comment: @huynhquancam I mean 2 different apps, no 2 environments. It's all in order to avoid facebook limits :)

Comment: @Saqib I read the article and will try this. It is about one application but this method is probably good for many too. But do you know any way to change only app_id and secret_key before each request?

Comment: Do you know how to resolve following error: `No route matches {:action=>"passthru", :controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :format=>nil, :provider=>:facebook_app2} missing required keys: [:provider]` ? Below the article one has the same, but the solution doesn't work.